# What does this dial on my wire stripper do?

Tags: wiring, tools

I recently got a wire stripper online which has a slightly more robust version of the 'hold both ends of a wire and pull' mechanism for stripping wire. It works great, but it has a bit of a mysterious feature

[image: wire strippers with dial circled]
[image: close up of dial]

There's a stiff little dial that has a + and - symbol. It doesn't seem attached to anything. There's no obvious movement anywhere else. It *feels* like it adjusts the amount of pressure needed to pull the handles together  but I'm not actually sure. It has no manual (its cheap) so I can't read the manual.

So what *does* this dial do, and am I in mortal peril fiddling with it? If it has a name, what is it?

Comment: probably just a decoration

Comment: Likely for pressure, as you say, to compensate for different sheathing thickness. Can't say for certain, mine's a different design. My older one had a little slider on the top to set that. My current one is just supposed to be 'smart' & figure it out for itself.

Comment: @jsotola could be the mimics in that magical foreign land of cheap things, saw the OEM tool they were copying had that knob, so they added it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dial adjusts the internal jaw of the clamps that hold the wire. If you loosen the Philips screws a tad the dial should turn easier. The movement is very small.

Comment: I have found that this adjustment only applies to very small wire.